# create another mysql database help performance?

Tags: mysql

I want to know if I use different databases can help performs.

I have one big table in support_chat with more than 5 million rows and I need to scan this all  the time (3s with ajax) to check new messages on support. If I move this table to another db in the same computer, can it help anything? (let users, sells, comments table faster)

eg:

db1:

```
    users table
    sells table
    comments table
    support_chat table // move this table to db2
```

db2:

```
suport_chat table
```